# Python dataframe column update, replace as per where condition help required

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below are SQL queries to update Date in new format

```
update data set Date=[Time Period]+'-01-01' where Frequency='0'

update data set Date=replace([Time Period],'Q1','-01-01')
where Frequency='2' and substring([Time Period],5,2)='Q1'

update data set Date=replace([Time Period],'Q2','-04-01')
where Frequency='2' and substring([Time Period],5,2)='Q2'

update data set Date=replace([Time Period],'Q3','-07-01')
where Frequency='2' and substring([Time Period],5,2)='Q3'

update data set Date=replace([Time Period],'Q4','-10-01')
where Frequency='2' and substring([Time Period],5,2)='Q4'

update data set Date=replace([Time Period],'M','-')+'-01'
where Frequency='3' and len([Time Period])=7

update data set Date=replace([Time Period],'M','-0')+'-01' 
where Frequency='3' and len([Time Period])=6
```

Now I have loaded same data into python data frame,

Sample data from data frame with comma separated.
Column: **Time Period** is the input data and **Date** column is output date, I need to convert  **Time Period** to column Date format.

```
Frequency,Time Period,Date
0,2008,2008-01-01
0,1961,1961-01-01
2,2009Q1,2009-04-01
2,1975Q4,1975-10-01
2,2007Q3,2007-04-01
2,1959Q4,1959-10-01
2,1965Q4,1965-07-01
2,2008Q3,2008-07-01
3,1969M2,1969-02-01
3,1994M12,1994-12-01
3,1990M1,1990-01-01
3,1994M10,1994-10-01
3,2012M11,2012-11-01
3,1994M3,1994-03-01
```

Please let me know how to update Date as per above condition in python.

Comment: Could you please post sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so one could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to do with the input data in order to get output data set? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Max, I have added sample data, please check and help on this...

Comment: this is much better now! Please also post a __desired__ data set. Or is it the `Date` column - is it already your desired result?

Comment: Yes Max, **Date** is the **desired** column

Answer (score 0):

This is bit tricky to use a **vectorized apparoach** when adding different offsets.

Consider the following approach:

**Source DF:**

```
In [337]: df
Out[337]:
    Frequency Time Period
0           0        2008
1           0        1961
2           2      2009Q1
3           2      1975Q4
4           2      2007Q3
5           2      1959Q4
6           2      1965Q4
7           2      2008Q3
8           3      1969M2
9           3     1994M12
10          3      1990M1
11          3     1994M10
12          3     2012M11
13          3      1994M3
```

**Solution:**

```
In [338]: %paste
df[['y','mm']] = (df['Time Period']
                    .replace(['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
                             ['M0', 'M3', 'M6', 'M9'],
                             regex=True)
                    .str.extract('(\d{4})M?(\d+)?', expand=True))

df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.pop('y'), format='%Y', errors='coerce')
                .values.astype('M8[M]') \
              + \
              pd.to_numeric(df.pop('mm'), errors='coerce') \
                .fillna(0).astype(int).values * np.timedelta64(1, 'M')) \
             .astype('M8[D]')
## -- End pasted text --
```

**Result:**

```
In [339]: df
Out[339]:
    Frequency Time Period       Date
0           0        2008 2008-01-01
1           0        1961 1961-01-01
2           2      2009Q1 2009-01-01
3           2      1975Q4 1975-10-01
4           2      2007Q3 2007-07-01
5           2      1959Q4 1959-10-01
6           2      1965Q4 1965-10-01
7           2      2008Q3 2008-07-01
8           3      1969M2 1969-03-01
9           3     1994M12 1995-01-01
10          3      1990M1 1990-02-01
11          3     1994M10 1994-11-01
12          3     2012M11 2012-12-01
13          3      1994M3 1994-04-01
```

## EDIT by Scott Boston please remove if you find a better way.

```
df[['y','mm']] = (df['Period']
                    .replace(['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
                             ['M1', 'M4', 'M7', 'M10'],
                             regex=True)
                    .str.extract('(\d{4})M?(\d+)?', expand=True))

df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.pop('y'), format='%Y', errors='coerce')
                .values.astype('M8[M]') \
              + \
              pd.to_numeric(df.pop('mm'), errors='coerce') \
                .fillna(1).astype(int).values - 1 * np.timedelta64(1, 'M')) \
             .astype('M8[D]')
```

Output:

```
    Frequency  Time   Period       Date
0           0     0     2008 2008-01-01
1           1     0     1961 1961-01-01
2           2     2   2009Q1 2009-01-01
3           3     2   1975Q4 1975-10-01
4           4     2   2007Q3 2007-07-01
5           5     2   1959Q4 1959-10-01
6           6     2   1965Q4 1965-10-01
7           7     2   2008Q3 2008-07-01
8           8     3   1969M2 1969-02-01
9           9     3  1994M12 1994-12-01
10         10     3   1990M1 1990-01-01
11         11     3  1994M10 1994-10-01
12         12     3  2012M11 2012-11-01
13         13     3   1994M3 1994-03-01
```

Comment: for Time Period: 1969M2, 1994M12, 1990M1 ,1994M10,2012M11, 1994M3, gives wrong results... could you please update revised script.

Comment: @MaxU please remove if you don't agree.